# My method to send values of performance counters to Graphite is very slow. What is the bottleneck? And how to improve?

Tags: performance, powershell, performancecounter

Below I have some code to get the values of instances of performance counters (which are instantiated once a page is visited) and send them to Graphite to display graphs in the following format:

`[Path in Graphite (e.g., metric.pages.Counter1)] [value of counter] [epoch time]`

To do this I made the following code where the `writer` is configured correctly to work:

```
# Get all paths to MultipleInstance counters and averages that start with "BLABLA" and 
# put them into an array and get the epoch time 
$pathsWithInstances = (get-counter -ListSet BLABLA*) | select -ExpandProperty PathsWithInstances
$epochtime = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -UFormat %s))

# This functions splits the path (e.g., \BLABLA Web(welcome)\Page Requests) into three 
# parts: the part before the 
# opening brace (the CounterCategory, e.g., "\BLABLA Web"), the part in between the braces 
# (the page or 
# service, e.g., "welcome"), and the part after the closing brace (the name of the test, 
# e.g., 
# "\Page Requests"). We obtain the metric out of this information and send it to 
# Graphite.
enter code here
foreach ($pathWithInstance in $pathsWithInstances)
{   
    $instanceProperties = $pathWithInstance.Split('()')
    $counterCategory = $instanceProperties[0]

    if ($counterCategory -eq ("\BLABLA Web") )
    {
        # Replace the * with nothing so that counters that are used to display the 
        # average (e.g., \BLABLAWeb(*)\Page Requests) are displayed on top in the  
        # Graphite directory.

        $pagePath = $instanceProperties[1].Replace('*','')
        $nameOfTheTest = $instanceProperties[2]

        # Countername which is used in Graphite path gets whitespace and backslash 
        # removed in the name used for the path in Graphite (naming conventions)
        $counterName = $nameOfTheTest.Replace(' ','').Replace('\','')
        $pathToPerfCounter = $pathWithInstance
        $pathInGraphite = "metrics.Pages." + $pagePath + $counterName

        #Invoked like this since otherwise the get-counter [path] does not seem to work
       $metricValue = [int] ((Get-Counter "$pathToPerfCounter").countersamples | select -
             property cookedvalue).cookedvalue           
        $metric = ($pathInGraphite + " " + $metricValue +  " " + $epochTime)

        $writer.WriteLine($metric) 
        $writer.Flush() 

    }

}
```

Unfortunately this code is very slow. It takes about one second for every counter to send a value. Does someone see why it is so slow and how it can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting one counter at a time, and it takes a second for Get-Counter to get and "Cook" the values.  Get-Counter will accept an array of counters, and will sample, "cook" and return them all in that same second.  You can speed it up by sampling them all at once, and then parsing the values from the array of results:

```
$CounterPaths = (
 '\\Server1\Memory\Page Faults/sec',
 '\\Server1\Memory\Available Bytes'
 )


(Measure-Command {
foreach ($CounterPath in $CounterPaths)
{Get-Counter -counter $counterpath}
}).TotalMilliseconds

(Measure-Command {
 Get-Counter $CounterPaths
 }).TotalMilliseconds


2017.4693
1012.3012
```

Example:

```
foreach ($CounterSample in (Get-Counter $CounterPaths).Countersamples)
{
  "Path = $($CounterSample.path)"
  "Metric = $([int]$CounterSample.CookedValue)"
}

Path = \\Server1\memory\page faults/sec
Metric = 193
Path = \\Server1\memory\available bytes
Metric = 1603678208
```

Comment: Hmm well I only need the counters with `BLABLA` in the name... When do I do the parsing?

Comment: This seems like the *real* solution though. I'll do my best.

Comment: Is it possible to use something else then cooked value to speed it up?

Comment: Your $pathInGraphite appears to be derived from the counter path name, so you just need to get that and the cooked value for the metric from each sample. You can do the parsing as go through the loop to read the samples, or you can do it up front, creating a hash table to associate the counter path names with a Graphite path name.

Comment: And this `Get-Counter $CounterPaths` does not work. How can I possibly invoke get-counter with a variable??
`

Comment: It works for me, and you can substitute your own computer name in the sample code to verify it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try one last time and otherwise I will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm interesting. This foreach loop and putting strings into it works? I can use that to send to the Graphite server?

Comment: And is there a way to get the counter-name?

Comment: Poke at it and experiment with it a while.  I think you'll get it.

Comment: This    `$CounterPaths = (get-counter -ListSet BLABLA*) | select -ExpandProperty PathsWithInstances` just does not work. It does not return any instances. I think the error is there. Tonight I will give up though and look at it tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright sleeping helped: I was not running PowerShell as administrator :-) Thanks for all your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Start-Job` cmdlet, to create separate threads for each counter.

Here is a simple example of how to take the Counter Paths and pass them into an asynchronous ScriptBlock:

```
$CounterPathList = (Get-Counter -ListSet Processor).PathsWithInstances.Where({ $PSItem -like '*% Processor Time' });

foreach ($CounterPath in $CounterPathList) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { (Get-Counter -Counter $args[0]).CounterSamples.CookedValue; } -ArgumentList $CounterPath;
}

# Call Receive-Job down here, once all jobs are finished
```

**IMPORTANT**: The above example uses PowerShell version 4.0's "method syntax" for filtering objects. Please make sure you're running PowerShell version 4.0, or change the `Where` method to use the traditional `Where-Object` instead.

Comment: Within your foreach loop, instead of simply executing the code for each counter, wrap the command in `Start-Job`. That ought to speed up the process, if you have a lot of counters.

Comment: In the if-statement (I have two if-statements in the real code to check for category names) or in the foreach loop?

Comment: You could put it in either place, depending on where you want to do the processing. The `ScriptBlock` that you pass into the `Start-Job` cmdlet can do the parsing of the counter paths, or you can do that in the "main" thread, before passing the counter into the `ScriptBlock` for retrieval and submittal to Graphite.

Comment: Right now I just put everything in a script-block like `Start-Job -Scriptblock { everything in the foreach loop }` and that does not work. It says `Missing an argument for parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Specify a parameter`. How exactly do I work with this Scriptblock?

Comment: Hey, I just posted an example, showing you how to pass the Counter Path into the `ScriptBlock` using the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Comment: A colleague is using the `CounterCategory` class and `GetInstance` and then looping through them which is a way faster. It is probably possible to use this class as well.